# React - Importing MP3 File

Tags: reactjs, webpack, import

I'm trying to add sound effects to my UI but it keeps telling me that it

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'file-loader'
```

I have a .mp3 file in this directory structure `src/core/sounds/click.mp3` and in my `login.tsx`
file I'm importing it

```
import soundPack  from '../../../core/sounds/soundpack.mp3';
```

My in my WebPack file I have the following

```
        {
            test: /\.(mp3)/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'core/sounds'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: and file-loader is in `package.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not installed file-loader

please see [file-loader npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader)

Comment: You are correct not sure how I didn't catch that but it is installed now and compiles succesfully but does not play the sound when I play it.